# Is there a more efficient way to modify an array's contents within a function when only given a pointer to the first element?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

I am simply wondering if there is a more efficient way to implement a function as opposed to the way I have done it. The constraints of the function are that the parameters MUST remain the same, and I can only edit what lies within the function. Here is my code:

```
void function_four(int* arr, int size, int& lowest, int& highest){
    lowest = *arr + 2;
    highest = *arr + 2;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int* valptr = arr+i;
        *valptr += 2;
        int val = *valptr;
        if(val > highest){
            highest = val;
        }

        if(val < lowest){
            lowest = val;
        }
        
    }
}
```

The purpose of this function is to update every value within the array by adding two.

Although this solution works, I am simply curious to know if a better solution exists without changing the function parameters.

At first, I had two different for loops: one for updating each array value, and another for finding the min/max values in the array. However, I merged them together in order to decrease runtime. Any other fixes would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This requires measurements but I doubt that your usage of `valptr` is more efficient than simply accessing the array with `operator[]` (and the same applies to using `*arr`). Since it makes the code less readable I wouldn't do it without a good reason.

Comment: fwiw, you can make the last `if` an `else if` to save you one comparison each loop. But as others have said, the proof of the pudding is in the eating. If you really want to know about efficiency, start timing you code.

Comment: improving performance without profiling is useless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest issue in your code isn't the array, but the reads from and writes back to `highest` and  `lowest`. The compiler in general cannot prove whether `highest` and `lowest` alias some members of `arr`, especially given the unbound size.

That is to say, `*valptr += 2;` could change `lowest` or `highest`, and `highest = val` could change any element of `arr[]`. The aliasing works both ways.

Therefore, the easy fix here is to store the two results in local variables, and only update `highest` and `lowest` after the loop. The compiler can easily prove that these two local variables do not alias `arr`, precisely since they're local.

Comment: I haven't seen a modern compiler that doesn't generate equally good optimised code for either of *(x+index) or x[index] for a long time now. I prefer the latter for readability.

Comment: The OP's code does access *highest and *lowest inside the loop for i=0,1 so the compiler is correct to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @MartinBrown: I don't understand your comments. Both `*(arr+index)` and `arr[index]` are subject to aliasing the other two arguments. Also, `highest` and `lowest` are accessed and potentially modified for all `i`, not just 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is quite efficient, the only thing you can do is to start the loop from index 1 instead of 0, since we've already processed the first element for initializing lowest and highest.

Here's the modified version of your function:

```
void function_four(int* arr, int size, int& lowest, int& highest) {
    lowest = arr[0]+2; //Initialize to the first element of the array
    highest = arr[0]+2; //Initialize to the first element of the array
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) { // Start from index 1
        arr[i] += 2; //Update the array value by adding 2
        if (arr[i] > highest) {
            highest = arr[i];
        }

        if(arr[i] < lowest){
            lowest = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This modification reduces the number of times we access the arr pointer inside the loop, which can result in a slight improvement in performance. Your function is already quite efficient, and this small optimization further enhances its efficiency.

Comment: Thankyou @wohlstad for rightly pointing it out, I have modified my answer. So the only modifications to his code is to start the Index from 1 on the for loop (Very less impact), and accessing the array values directly 'arr[i]'

Comment: Using `operator[]` is indeed more readable but the performance issue (which is what the OP actually asked about) requires measurements to be done in the actual case the OP is facing. Same goes to the issue of one less iteration. From my exprience I very much doubt either will have a noticable effect.

Comment: You forgot to increase `arr[0]`...

Comment: OP uses `*(arr + i)` which is `arr[i]`, so no performance differences (but readability changes :-) )...

Answer (score 0):

With [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element), you might do

```
void function_four(int* arr, int size, int& lowest, int& highest){
    int* const begin = arr;
    int* const end = arr + size;
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        *it += 2;
    }
    std::tie(lowest, highest) = std::minmax_element(begin, end);
}
```

That also covers the aliasing point of MSalters :-)

Comment: This does change the code to two passes. As the question already notes, that can be sub-optimal (and there's a hint of profiling in the question).